# Why does this instruction not work?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi I'm trying to count using keys only and get an error message when using this line
`self.response.out.write(A.all(keys_only=True).count(100000000))`

The error message I get is
`TypeError: all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys_only'`

Isn't it supposed to work this way? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
        `

UPDATE: I found this way worked:

```
    query = A.all()
    query._keys_only = True        
    self.response.out.write(query.count(100000000))
```

Comment: Come more context to your code would be helpful.  Specifically, how  A is created (it looks like a query).

Comment: A is a SearchableModel where this has been reported to be an issue. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with SearchableModel and keys_only. you can do some think like this.

```
query = A.all()
query._keys_only = True
```